# DbType equivalent to SqlDbType.Bit

Tags: c#, enterprise-library, enterprise-library-5, sqldbtype, dbtype

Does anyone know what is the DbType equivalent to SqlDbType.Bit?

I am trying to convert

```
param[0] = new SqlParameter("@Status", SqlDbType.Bit);
param[0].Value = Status;
```

to

```
db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@Status", <DbType dbType>, Status);
```

but I don't know which DbType to use to represent a single Bit. Any ideas?

Comment: a boolean perhaps? Altough the DbType is Bit and the .NET type is bool, so what do you mean by "DbType equivalent to SqlDbType.Bit ?"

Comment: I agree, Boolean, as it's stored as either 0 or 1.

Comment: @Freeman wouldn't a boolean take true or false? and bit takes 1, 0..

Comment: Exactly, so your question is?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The database type `bit` is represented as a boolean on the server side, so the corresponding `DbType` value is `DbType.Boolean`.

Answer (score 10):

[`DbType.Boolean`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dbtype.aspx):

> A simple type representing Boolean values of true or false.

[`SqlDbType.Bit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.data.sqldbtype.aspx):

> [Boolean](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.boolean.aspx). An unsigned numeric value that can be 0, 1, or null.

Their description's don't quite match up, but since `Bit` is described as being a `Boolean`, it's the most appropriate match.

Comment: Would something like this work then - `cmd.Parameters.Add("@isActive", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = False`

Comment: Is it most appropriate? C# does know `null`, as do nullable `BIT` fields in SQL. SQL Server, for instance, accepts `0/1/NULL` only rather than `true/false`.

Comment: @dakab - there are various issues here that I didn't include in my answer - such as the fact that SQL Server doesn't have an actual boolean data type (`bit` is described in documentation as a numeric type) and that, if SQL Server *were* to implement the proper (SQL Standard) boolean data type then, due to its use of three-valued logic, that type should support `true`, `false` and `unknown`, plus the (standard for every type) absence of a value via `null`.

Answer (score 3):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype.aspx

enum SqlDbType - Bit: **Boolean**. An unsigned numeric value that can be 0, 1, or null.

Answer (score 2):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhkx04c4, I would say `DbType.Boolean`
         A simple type representing Boolean values of true or false.

Comment: This doesn't take into account that the OP was asking for `SQLDbType` which does not include a Boolean type